# I want to use Quartz to make a single color image a different color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I'm sure the answer for this exists on stackoverflow, but I've been looking and haven't been able to find it yet. Essentially, I have several images with transparent backgrounds and some black imagery, I want to be able to change the color of the black part to some other arbitrary color.

I'm relatively sure this is achievable with [Quartz Image Masking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html), but I haven't been able to find any good examples, so that is what I'm looking for. Other solutions are also welcome.

Thanks!!!

**UPDATE:** I think I'm pretty close with this code... but my mask isn't working. My `UIView` does get filled with the fill color though, but it's just a giant rectangle, not clipped whatsoever.

**UPDATE #2:** I am even closer now (I think) with the following code. The problem is that my background is now black, rather than transparent.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -rect.size.height);

CGImageRef maskImage = [self.image CGImage];
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, maskImage);

[_colorToChangeInto setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: What happens if you clip BEFORE you fill? A clip affects only the drawing that you do afterwards.

Comment: Same effect. Just a big box of the fill color.

Comment: Hmmm. If I get rid of the colorSpace BS and just use the image as the mask directly, I get an image that is close to what I want, but the background is black, rather than transparent. (I need to flip coordinates, which I can do via `CGContextScaleCTM(mainViewContentContext, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(mainViewContentContext, 0, -rect.size.height);`.) That solution courtesy of another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351807/18961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is already in the question above. It wasn't quite working because I was creating the image in IB (in a storyboard), and hadn't set the background color. Somehow that defaulted to Black. SO FRUSTRATING!!!

Anyway, after I changed the background color to transparent, the following code works like a charm!

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -rect.size.height);

CGImageRef maskImage = [self.image CGImage];
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, maskImage);

[_colorToChangeInto setFill];
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```